# RecyclerView horizontal layout_width match parent

Tags: android-recyclerview

Horizontal layout_width match parent issue. I am attaching the view picture below, what I want is all item in horizontal to be on same width and height.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_itemName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Sheet Set"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_itemDesc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Pc with 4 top heaming"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```